# XSL 1.0 Replace value and then remove duplicates from xml variable

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm sorry if this is repetitive, but I am struggling to resolve this. I have a xml variable. I have xsl variable which has xml like this:

```
<root>
    <data>
        <GroupItems>
            <row id="30" class="A100"/>

            <row id="50" class="B100"/>

            <row id="100" class="A100"/>

            <row id="20" class="C100"/>

        </GroupItems>
    </data>
</root>
```

I have to replace "id" value from the preceding sibling node based on "class" value. The duplicate preceding class="A100" has to be removed but the "id" value has to be copied to the first occurrence node.  In this case required output is:

```
<root>
    <data>
        <GroupItems>
            <row id="100" class="A100"/>

            <row id="50" class="B100"/>

            <row id="20" class="C100"/>

        </GroupItems>
    </data>
</root>
```

The below code removing duplicates from the string but I need to replace the id value (id="100" ).

```
 <xsl:for-each select="CSharp:NodeList($RawInstruction1)//GroupItems/row[(@class = preceding-sibling::row/@class)]">
```

Comment: can't see your code i'm afraid

Comment: I have added code.

Comment: How do you know which id to keep (30 or 100)?  It look like you have a template and updating from your classes.  It would be better to give all your inputs and then the required output.

Comment: ID value may be anything. XML was a output from the Stored Procedure. The SP joins two columns and giving a single output xml. So I just need to replace the first xml output ID with the sibling for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the identity transformation template and then add a key to "group" the `row` elements by the `class` attribute, then you add templates to copy the `id` attribute from the last `row` in each group to the first and another template to suppress copying the remaining duplicated `row`s in a group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="class-group" match="GroupItems/row" use="@class"/>

  <xsl:template match="GroupItems/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('class-group', @class)[1])]/@id">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('class-group', ../@class)[last()]/@id"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="GroupItems/row[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('class-group', @class)[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRn